# lost diactric marks after export data form hive table to .txt

Tags: hive, export

I export text data form table in HIVE to .txt file in this way:

hive -e "select * from table_name;" > table_name.txt

When I open "table_name.txt" I do not have diactric marks in there (ą, ć, ę, ł, ń, ó, ś, ź, ż.). 
How I can export text data from HIVE to have diactric marks in the .txt file?

Comment: which version of hive are you using?

Comment: looks like it is fixed in hive 0.14.. follow the comments section of this link..
http://answers.mapr.com/questions/162978/hive-issue-when-querying-on-hive-013.html